# How to edit Arrays in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have [String, AnyObject] dictionary in my code like below one and I want to modify the values inside the "boolArray", but I Xcode throws me "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject'" error.

Is there any simple way to change the value of this "boolArray"?

```
var dictionary : NSDictionary = [
        "foo" : 0,
        "bar" : "string",
        "boolArray" : [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]  
    ]

dictionary["boolArray"]![0] = true // [!] Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject!'
```

Comment: You should not be working with NSDictionary in Swift. Dictionary is a more powerful class available in swift that is mutable by default. Furthermore its automatically bridged from objective c. Any way, the answers given below will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abizern answer is partly true. You will need to change NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary. You will also have to change

```
dictionary["boolArray"]![0] = true
```

To

```
dictionary["boolArray"]!.setObject(true, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: When I try this in a Playground, I get the following: `Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT` - do you know why this happens?

Comment: Worked perfectly in my environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is with your type.  `NSDictionary` is immutable.  Try declaring it as `NSMutableDictionary` instead.